# Do graduate schools read your undergraduate application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

If you apply to a university to be enrolled as an undergraduate, and are rejected, and then apply to the same university's graduate program, will they look at and/or take into consideration your undergraduate application?  Or is it considered irrelevant?

Answer (score 22):

Irrelevant.

Indeed, I suspect that in most or all graduate programs, those reading your graduate application do not have access to your undergraduate application, won't know that you applied to their undergraduate program, and would not care even if they knew.

Comment: And even if someone knew and cared, who is going to dig for these old applications!

Comment: Is this just a hunch, or are you speaking from personal experience?

Answer (score 6):

I would imagine that they would consider it irrelevant. If you went to a different institution and received a degree, then I think they would be more interested in that. A person can change/mature a lot during their undergraduate degree.